# Query on Http Basic Authentication in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Being new to Spring security, was trying a simple REST GET call with HTTP Basic Authentication. Scenario :
For correct usr/pwd, gives http ok. Then I change only the pwd. For incorrect pwd also it gives 200 ok. And the server log says :
*o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate*
Question - how do I reauth every time and send http 401 unauthorized to the client?
Code :

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("In securityFilterChain with HttpSecurity");
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()//Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService initUser() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("basic")
                .password(encoder.encode("basic123"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean 
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(initUser())
                .and()
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: HTTP basic (with the browser at least) after succesful authentication doesn't re-authenticate and automatically sends the right header. YOu would need to stop your browser, close it and retry.

Comment: Is there a way to force reauth in the GET call from controller or security config?

Comment: Historically there was an option to set to always re-authenticate. But I'm not sure that still exists, next to that you are still at he perills of your browser to include the new or the old header. So that might not even fix it.